# Expresión regular para obtener número seguido de una palabra

Tags: java, regex

Quería saber cómo puedo, a partir de una expresión regular, localizar un número cualquiera seguido de una palabra.

Yo tengo un texto en el cual detecto una serie de palabras y ahora lo que quiero es que me localice el número que hay delante de esas palabras. Por ejemplo, `Hay 3 cajas en casa`, quiero que me localice solo `3 cajas`.

```
"(^|\\W)("+cajas+")($|\\W)"
```

Comment: lo títulos dan una idea global, la descripción va en el cuerpo del mensaje

Comment: no es mas simple con substring?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Por qué estás pasando `cajas` como variable? ¿Es realmente una variable o un texto literal? Además, podrías leer los 5 puntos que se piden en **[la descripción de la etiqueta regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)** y [edit] tu pregunta para incorporarlos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres una expresión regular que te detecte un número seguido de una palabra en español, sería algo como esto:

```
"\\d+ [A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÑÜáéíóúñü]+"
```

Básicamente estás buscando un número formado por uno o más caracteres (`\\d+`), seguido de un espacio (), seguido de caracteres de la `a` a la `z`, vocales con tilde, `u` con diéresis o la letra `ñ`, lo mismo en mayúsculas que en minúsculas.

Si pueden existir o no espacios entre el número y la palabra, la expresión sería:

```
"\\d+ *[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÑÜáéíóúñü]+"
```

Que basícamente es decir que los espacios pueden ser 0 o más usando el cuantificador `*`.

[Aquí tienes](https://regex101.com/r/3fhWQB/2) un ejemplo funcionando.

En caso de que quieras detectar solo una lista específica de palabras, podrías incluirlas en un grupo sin captura con varias alternativas, por ejemplo:

```
"(?:^| )(\\d+ *(?:casa|cajas|lápices))(?:$|\\W)"
```

La anterior expresión solo detectará los números seguidos de las palabras `casa`, `cajas` o `lápices`, ignorando el resto. Siguiendo las recomendaciones de @Mariano, he situado que antes del número solo pueda haber un inicio de línea o un espacio y que después de la palabra pueda ir solamente un final de línea o cualquier caracter diferente de un caracter alfanumérico (esto debes ajustarlo dependiendo de tus necesidades).

[Aquí tienes](https://regex101.com/r/JMROgG/2/) un ejemplo de esto.

Comment: ¿Para que los paréntesis exteriores? Además, si bien `\s` incluye a espacios, en realidad es mucho más que eso. Para que coincida con espacios, se usan... espacios. Y en tu última expresión, no se garantiza que sean palabras, por ejemplo podría coincidir con "1 casa" dentro del texto "5.1 casamientos".

Comment: Es verdad @Mariano, buenos puntos, en cuanto tenga una oportunidad libre lo perfecciono ;)

Comment: @ElChiniNet gracias me sirvió mucho! Y tengo otra duda mi expresión ahora es esta "(^|\\W)(\\d+)("+cajas+")($|\\W)" es decir que me devuelve 3 cajas pero si quisiera que esa expresión también me pudiera localizar cajas 3 es decir, que el numero pueda estar tanto delante como detrás de la palabra, seria posible? o tendría que hacer otra expresión?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola @Jumans, sí, sería posible, una forma fácil es separar distintas expresiones dentro de un grupo sin captura: `(?:expr 1 | expr 2 | expr 3)`. Eso sería, expresión 1 o expresión 2 o expresión 3, haría match con la primera de ellas en la que se cumpliera el patrón. Solo debes tener en cuenta que si tienes algo como `2 cajas 3` y quisieras que haga match de `2 cajas` y de `cajas 3` tendrías que hacer un _lookahead_.

Comment: El problema esque ahora tengo el siguiente codigo

"((^|\\W)(\\d+)(\\s*)("+diccionario+")($|\\W))"

donde diccionario es un archivo con varios terminos, entonces si en dicionario tengo cajas y silla me tendria que encontrar 3 cajas y silla 4. Con el diccionario se me complica un poco creo.

Gracias!

Comment: @Jumans, si no tienes que hacer _lookahead_, pudes hacer algo como [lo que te comentaba anteriormente](https://regex101.com/r/PRaTu9/1).